# Filtro com duas tabelas sem relacionamento - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, query, oracle

Estou com problemas para fazer filtro com dois models diferentes. O problema é que não existe relacionamento entre as tabelas.

Pois é =/

A modelagem foi feita por outra pessoa, que disse que não seria possível fazer o relacionamento e que eu teria que fazer com o que tenho. Assim, em alguns módulos precisei fazer algumas consultas e mais consultas para sanar isso e disponibilizar alguns dados para o usuário.

Eu tenho uma view (oracle) de ferramentas 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E tenho uma tabela de pedidos, onde registro o inventory_item_id e o part_number da ferramenta solicitada
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho uma view com um filtro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<!-- Filtro -->
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
        <div class="card-header py-3">
          <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Filtro</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <form action="/historico" method="get">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-2 px-1">
                    <label for="estado">Estado</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="estado">
                        <option value="" selected disabled>Selecione um status</option>
                        <option value="Aberto" >Aberto</option>
                        <option value="Submetido" >Submetido</option>
                        <option value="Entregue" >Entregue</option>
                        <option value="Cancelado" >Cancelado</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2 px-1">
                    <label for="data">Data</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" value="" name="data" >
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 px-1">
                    <label for="item">Item</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="item" >
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 px-1">
                    <label for="descricao">Descrição da ferramenta</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="descricao" >

                </div>

                <div class="col-md-1  align-self-end px-1 button">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="fa fa-search fa-1x"></i></button>
                </div>


            </div>
          </form>

        </div>
    </div>
```

E o meu controlador:

```
$pedidos = DetalhePedido::when(Request::input('estado'),function($query){
        $query->where('estado_linha',Request::input('estado'));
    })
    ->when(Request::input('data'),function($query){
        $query->where('creation_date',  'like', '%' . strtoupper(Request::input('data')) . '%');
    })
    ->when(Request::input('item'),function($query){
        $query->where('item',  'like', '%' . strtoupper(Request::input('item')) . '%');
    })
    ->when(Request::input('descricao'),function($query){
        $query->where('description','like', '%' . strtoupper(Request::input('descricao')) . '%');
    })->paginate(10);


    $estado = Request::input('estado');
    $data = Request::input('data');
    $item = Request::input('item');
    $descricao = Request::input('descricao');


    return view('historico', compact('pedidos', 'estado', 'data', 'item', 'descricao'));
```

Filtrando por **Estado** e por **Data** funciona normalmente. O problema é que querem também filtro por  **Item** e **Descrição**, que são colunas da view oracle e que não tem relacionamento.

Existe alguma forma de sanar isso?

Comment: Eu vejo que esse seu código pode ficar menor , e por que o cara disse que não da para relacionar ele é burro ou o que? Só não da para relacionar se o banco não é relacional se for meu amigo, pode mandar o cara voltar para algoritmos por que ele não está apto para o mercado

Comment: Pois é. Isso me deu um trabalhão, mas consegui resolver.

Comment: Qual versão do Laravel?

Comment: Opa, Lucas. É a 5.8

Comment: Melhora esse código da para gastar umas 4 linhas  esse seu código nessa versão

Comment: Qual a sua sugestão?

Comment: Vou refazer seu código no modo de hoje em dia e você avalia pode ser?

Comment: Sim sim, claro!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver. Deu um trabalhão por que pensei em várias possibilidades, mas depois vi que era simples.

Bastou fazer uma consulta consulta à tabela de ferramentas com o dado do input e armazenar o numa variável, depois a query normal com o campo inventory_item_id do primeiro elemento.

Ficou assim:

```
// Busca por itens solicitados
    $pedidos = DetalhePedido::when(Request::input('estado'),function($query){
        $query->where('estado_linha',Request::input('estado'));
    })
    ->when(Request::input('data'),function($query){
        $query->where('creation_date',  'like', '%' . strtoupper(Request::input('data')) . '%');
    })
    ->when(Request::input('item'),function($query){
        $frmtItem= Ferramenta::where('item',  'like', '%' .  Request::input('item'). '%')->get();
        $query->where('inventory_item_id', '=',  $ferramenta[0]->inventory_item_id );
    })
    ->when(Request::input('descricao'),function($query){
        $frmtDescription = Ferramenta::where('description',  'like', '%' .  strtoupper(Request::input('descricao')). '%')->get();
        $query->where('inventory_item_id', '=',  $frmt[0]->inventory_item_id );
    })->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo de código que você pode estar usando:

```
$pedidos = DetalhePedido::where('estado_linha', $request->estado)
           ->where('creation_date', 'like', '%'.strtoupper($request->data).'%')
           ->whereHas('ferramenta', function($query) use ($request){ 
               //WhereHas se usa para where relacionados caso não esteja relacionado pode usar o where como descrito antes do whereHas e puxar como você fez em baixo criando uma variável antes e passando os dados que deseja.
               $query->where('item', 'like', '%'.$request->item.'%');
            })
            ->whereHas('ferramenta', function($query) use ($request){
                $query->where('description', 'like', '%'.strtoupper($request->descricao).'%');
            })->paginate(10);
```

Outra dica que te passo é que quando for puxar somente um dado especifico use o `->first()` no lugar do `->get()` assim pega o primeiro registro.

Os WhereHas só reforçando é para relacionamento eu vejo que ferramenta precisaria está relacionado com DetalhePedido para te ajudar, mas caso não esteja use a forma anterior com `->first()` e passe para o where como mostrei nos exemplo, código mais curto e limpo.

Comment: Ah, ótimo. Irei testar. Quanto ao ->get(), foi intencional. Quando colei o código, ainda não havia finalizado. Precisei fazer outra validação, já que pode existir várias ferramentas com o mesmo trecho de entrada. Desta forma precisei do get pra carregar todas mesmo. Enfim. Obrigado pelo toque. Vou testar sua sugestão aqui.

Comment: Sim, como já mencionado não existe relacionamento. Por isso precisei falidar antes de setar a query.

Comment: Pode passar a query antes e mesmo assim ficaria menor que seu código anterior